# animate() , argument for faster movement of img

Tags: jquery

I want a way to move the img faster. What should I put there?

```
.animate({},'?');  


$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).keydown(function(key) {
    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
        // Left arrow key pressed
        case 37:
            $('img').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
            break;
        // Up Arrow Pressed
        case 38:
            $('img').animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
            break;
        // Right Arrow Pressed
        case 39:
          $('img').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
            break;
        // Down Array Pressed
        case 40:
            $('img').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
            break;
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: Increase the distance?

Comment: no i just want it to cover the given distance faster

Comment: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/): *"Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The default duration is 400 milliseconds. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply input the number of milliseconds instead of a string:

```
.animate({}, 1000); // 1 second
.animate({}, 10); // 1/100 of a second
```

See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more info about that call. `'fast'` is the same as `200` btw.